# Rails flash.notice briefly appearing after reloads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller action in Rails as follows:

```
def register
 if logged_in?
   current_user().courses << Course.find(params[:course_id])
   flash.notice = 'Successfully registered!'
   redirect_to '/'
 else
   flash.alert = "You must be logged in"
   redirect_to '/courses'
 end
end
```

This is rendered in the `/courses` view as

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
   <div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>
```

However, when I go to a different route and then return to `/courses`, the notice briefly flashes before going away. Is this normal behavior? If so, why is it occurring? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: search your project and see if `flash.notice` is being set anywhere else or somehow duplicated by multiple controllers.  Also see https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html

Comment: This is most likely related to Turbolinks: "`Turbolinks will immediately restore the page from cache and display it as a preview while simultaneously loading a fresh copy from the network. This gives the illusion of instantaneous page loads for frequently accessed locations.`". You can check workarounds to the caching issue here: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/309#issuecomment-360278366

Comment: You can also check the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542471/rails-turbolinks-5-flash-messages

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the flash to show up again, use `flash.now` instead:

```
flash.now[:notice] = 'Successfully registered!'
```

As you are doing session detection directly in your controller methods, I highly recomend you to use action filters:

```
before_action :logged_in, only: [:register]

# ...

def register
  # ...
end
```

Here `logged_in` should be a method to make sure user is registered and logged in. Check [Filters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `"rails", "~> 7.0.6"` and I had to put the following into the `<head>` tag in `application.html.erb`:

```
<meta name="turbo-cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

The reason for this is because there is caching going on with Turbolinks enabled. This solution has one downside - it will remove the page caching illusion from your pages. If you can go without this, then this is the solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Rails 7.1 and ran into this issue. This is indeed due to turbo's [caching](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/building):

> Turbo Drive maintains a cache of recently visited pages. This cache
> serves two purposes: to display pages without accessing the network
> during restoration visits, and to improve perceived performance by
> showing temporary previews during application visits.

There's a quote specifically addressing this issue when using flash:

> Certain page elements are inherently temporary, like flash messages or
> alerts. If they’re cached with the document they’ll be redisplayed
> when it’s restored, which is rarely desirable. You can annotate such
> elements with data-turbo-temporary to have Turbo Drive automatically
> remove them from the page before it’s cached.

The solution for individual elements is to add a `data-turbo-temporary` attribute to the element to have turbo drive remove them before the page is cached.

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
   <div class="notice" data-turbo-temporary><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>
```